# How to have Apache Spark running on GPU?

Tags: apache-spark, cuda, opencl, gpu, cpu

I want to integrate apache spark with GPU but spark works on java while gpu uses CUDA/OpenCL so how do we merge them.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want to distribute your computation with GPUs using spark you don't necessary have to use java. You could use python (pyspark) with numba which have a cuda module.

For exemple you can apply this code if you want your worker nodes to compute operation (here gpu_function) on every blocks of your RDD.

```
rdd = rdd.mapPartition(gpu_function)
```

with :

```
def gpu_function(x):
    ...
    input = f(x)
    output = ...
    gpu_cuda[grid_size,block_size](input,output)
    return output
```

and :

```
from numba import cuda
@cuda.jit("(float32[:],float32[:])")
def gpu_cuda(input,output)
    output = g(input)
```

I advise you to take a look at the slideshare url : https://fr.slideshare.net/continuumio/gpu-computing-with-apache-spark-and-python  ,specificly slide 34.

You only need numba and cuda driver install on every worker node.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few libraries that helps with this dilema.

The Databricks is working in a solution for Spark with TensorFlow that will allow you to use the GPUs of your cluster, or your machine.

If you want to find more about that there is a presentation of [Spark Summit Europe 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXItObf-qaI&feature=youtu.be) This presentation will show a little bit how TensorFrames works.

Other this is a post about [TensoFrames](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/10/27/gpu-acceleration-in-databricks.html) in DataBricks Blog.

And for more code information see the [Git of Tensorframes](https://github.com/databricks/tensorframes).